# SUMIF with VLOOKUP and Multiple Instances (Count)

Tags: excel, count, vlookup

I have the following input data:

| Filter | Date | Employee1 | Employee2 | Employee3 | Reason | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tip | 8/30/2022 | Brendan McGrath |  |  | Called In |  |
|  | 9/1/2022 | Matthew Wright |  |  | Reimbursement | 30.00 |
|  | 9/1/2022 | Robert Lombardo | Mike Houle |  | Bonus |  |
|  | 9/2/2022 | Mike Houle | Patrick Brown | Sean Brennan | Lost Tool | -10.00 |
|  | 9/3/2022 | Hector Murillo | Jonathan Guzman |  | Tip | 50.00 |
|  | 9/3/2022 | Mickey Krochko |  |  | Tip | 10.00 |
|  | 9/5/2022 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Alex Vargas |  |  | Tip | 20.00 |
|  |  | Robert Lombardo |  |  | Tip | 100.00 |

I want to calculate the total amount based on the following conditions:

1. For all employees with Reason equal `Tip` (the value of the **Filter** column)
2. If there are two or more employees on the same row with **Reason** equal to `Tip`, the **Amount** value is multiplied by the number of employees of that row.

The expected result for `Tip` would be: Hector and Jonathan (`2x50`) + Mickey (`10`) + Alex (`20`) + Robert(`100`) which is `230`.

I was trying to combine `SUMIF` with `VLOOKUP`, but I haven't gotten to the multiplication part yet to count how many employees are to receive each individual tip because I'm trying to work through the `SUMIF` with `VLOOKUP`.

**Note**: Updated the question based on the feedback received in the comment section.

Comment: Please check this: [Help Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and please update your question.

Comment: You might find sumproduct() interesting.

Comment: taking a quick look to your screenshot, please be aware you are invoking `VLOOKUP (lookup_value, table_array, col_index_num, [range_lookup])` with the fourth argument as default (approximate search not exact match). is this what you want?

Comment: True, second that probably using `SUMPRODUCT()` will be right, easy and incredible. More info on it *[SUMPRODUCT()](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function)*

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on cell `E11`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(G2:G10=A9),BYROW(--(C2:F10<>""), LAMBDA(row, SUM(row))), H2:H10)
```

you can achieve the same via `MMULT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(G2:G10=A9),MMULT(--(C2:F10<>""),{1;1;1;1}), H2:H10)
```

and here is the output:
[image: sample excel file]

### Explanation

`--(G2:G10=A9` returns `1` or `0` on a given cell that matches the value of `A9` (Tip).

```
BYROW(--(D2:F10<>""), LAMBDA(row, SUM(row)))
```

Calculates per row the sum of non empty rows (total number of employees per row)

Or similarly using matrix multiplication:

```
MMULT(--(C2:F10<>""),{1;1;1;1})
```

Then just do the `SUMPRODUCT` of the three arrays, so you have the total employee amount where the reason is `Tip` multiplied by Employee amount as per number of employee you have on each row. The result should be: Hector and Jonathan  `(2x50)` + Mickey `(10)` + Alex `(20)` + Robert`(100)` which is `230`.

**Note**: I am not 100% of what you are looking for in your question, but if that is the case, this may solve it.